Why does DiscretizeRegion show the error?
Sometimes (not always) the function DiscretizeRegion cannot work as needed. E.g. let us define 3 simple 3D regions:
D1 = ImplicitRegion[Abs[x - 1.7]^1.9/8 + Abs[y + 2.5]^1.9/8 + Abs[z - 1.7]^1.9/10 <=1, {x, y, z}]; 
D2 = ImplicitRegion[Abs[x - 1.7]^3.7/10 + Abs[y - 1.7]^3.7/10 + Abs[z - 2.5]^3.7/12 <= 1, {x, y, z}]; 
D3 = ImplicitRegion[Abs[x - 2.5]^1.9/8 + Abs[y + 2.5]^1.9/12 + Abs[z - 2.5]^1.9/10 <= 1, {x, y, z}];

Regions D1, D2, and D3 are valid and RegionPlot3D[{D1, D2, D3}, Axes -> True] renders as needed. But RegionMeasure fails to calculate the volume of union:
RegionMeasure[DiscretizeRegion[RegionUnion[D1, D2, D3]]]

Even the bounds of the union are calculated explicitly, RegionMeasure still fails
MINx = Min[1.7 - 8^(1/1.9), 1.7 - 10^(1/3.7), 2.5 - 8^(1/1.9)]; 
MAXx = Max[1.7 + 8^(1/1.9), 1.7 + 10^(1/3.7), 2.5 + 8^(1/1.9)];
MINy = Min[-2.5 - 8^(1/1.9), 1.7 - 10^(1/3.7), -2.5 - 12^(1/1.9)]; 
MAXy = Max[-2.5 + 8^(1/1.9), 1.7 + 10^(1/3.7), -2.5 + 12^(1/1.9)];
MINz = Min[1.7 - 10^(1/1.9), 2.5 - 12^(1/3.7), 2.5 - 10^(1/1.9)]; 
MAXz = Max[1.7 + 10^(1/1.9), 2.5 + 12^(1/3.7), 2.5 + 10^(1/1.9)];
RegionMeasure[DiscretizeRegion[RegionUnion[D1, D2, D3], {{MINx, MAXx},{MINy, MAXy},{MINz, MAXz}}]]


Try Method -> "MarchingCubes" or Method -> "DualMarchingCubes", with the bounds. (Method -> "RegionPlot3D" also works, but not as well.)

OK, I've tried. "DualMarchingCubes" works, "MarchingCubes" fails. Many thanks

One question, please. Help on DiscretizeRegion includes the following methods: "Continuation", "RegionPlot", "Boolean", "DiscretizeGraphics", "RegionPlot3D", "ContourPlot3D". What about "MarchingCubes" and "DualMarchingCubes"?

The error message from DiscretizeRegion[Ball[], Method -> "foo"] lists a few more methods. That's how I knew about them. Method -> "foo" is my way of poking the method option to see how it reacts..

BoundaryDiscretizeRegion

Method -> "MarchingCubes" and Method -> "DualMarchingCubes" work for me, although I need to set a slightly small MaxCellMeasure for "MarchingCubes" to work. Setting an even smaller MaxCellMeasure should result in a more accurate volume (and takes longer).
RegionMeasure[
 DiscretizeRegion[
  RegionUnion[D1, D2, D3], {{MINx, MAXx}, {MINy, MAXy}, {MINz, MAXz}},
   Method -> "DualMarchingCubes"]]
(*  206.937  *)

RegionMeasure[
 DiscretizeRegion[
  RegionUnion[D1, D2, D3], {{MINx, MAXx}, {MINy, MAXy}, {MINz, MAXz}},
   Method -> "MarchingCubes", MaxCellMeasure -> Length -> 0.5]]
(*  207.069  *)

RegionMeasure[
 DiscretizeRegion[
  RegionUnion[D1, D2, D3], {{MINx, MAXx}, {MINy, MAXy}, {MINz, MAXz}},
   Method -> "DualMarchingCubes", MaxCellMeasure -> Length -> 0.1]]
(*  207.829  *)

One may also control cell size with area or volume, such as MaxCellMeasure -> Volume -> 0.01.
